# Check if audio has already been loaded

Tags: flutter, just-audio

Question: How do I know whether or not the action of fetching the audio from a remote source (e.g. loading a player with  `player.setUrl(url1, preload: true)`), has already been done for this player?

```dart
    AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
     
    // Desired:
    // `true` if the `load()` action has been completed and that audio is currently 
    // `loaded` in the player (i.e. it is not necessary to fetch that audio again 
    // in order to play it)
    bool loaded = player.hasAudio; // false 

    // Once this is awaited, the player now has an audio `loaded`  
    await player.setUrl(url1, preload: true); 

    loaded = player.hasAudio; // true
```

In other words, what I *don't* want is calling `player.setUrl(url1, preload: true)` twice in a row, fetching the data twice.

I am looking for the property that is equivalent to `player.hasAudio` in my example above. Or another way to get a similar result.

Comment: Based on the state machine from the [doc](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)  I'm tempted to think that this might do the trick:
`bool loaded = player.processingState == ProcessingState.ready || player.processingState == ProcessingState.completed;`. 

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so based on the docs I can extrapolate this for my use case:

```
// `true` if the `load()` action has been completed and an audio is currently 
// `loaded` in the player
bool loaded = player.processingState == ProcessingState.ready ||
 player.processingState == ProcessingState.completed ||  
 player.processingState == ProcessingState.buffering;

// Or with less code but probably less intuitive
bool loaded = player.processingState.index > ProcessingState.loading.index;
```

`loaded` is `true` if player has been previously loaded and:

- playback is over :`player.playing == true && ProcessingState.completed`
- playback hasn't started: `player.playing == true && player.processingState == ProcessingState.ready`
- playback is in progress: `player.playing == true && player.processingState == ProcessingState.ready`
- playback has been paused:`player.playing == false && player.processingState == ProcessingState.ready`
- playback is resumed from paused state (triggers multiple state changes)

  1. `player.playing == true && player.processingState == ProcessingState.ready`
  2. then `player.playing == true && player.processingState == ProcessingState.buffering`
  3. then `player.playing == true && player.processingState == ProcessingState.ready`

From the docs:

> It is important to understand that even when `playing == true`, no sound
> will actually be audible unless ***`processingState == ready` which
> indicates that the buffers are filled and ready to play.***

---

As for the currently loaded `AudioSource`, I haven't yet found a way to expose the currently loaded `AudioSource`'s data...

Comment: While there is no getter for the current audio source as set by `player.setAudioSource`, you can get the current indexed audio source by looking at `player.sequence![player.currentIndex!]`, assuming they're not null (otherwise check first).

Comment: Thank you @RyanHeise, I'll check it out. Thanks for your great work on this package!